# Having a single label for multiple rows or columns in matplotlib.table

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, label

How can we assign a single label to multiple rows or columns in matplotlib.table

I have for example the following code where the `allInfo` is a pandas DataFrame.

```
the_table=plt.table(cellText=allInfo.values,
                    colLabels=allInfo.columns,
                    rowLabels=allInfo.index,
                    loc='right',
                    cellLoc='left')
```